# C# strange issue - unable to assign value from right to left variable

Tags: c#, xpath

I have a list Rows which holds 10 different records. I am looping this list in C# console app and inserting values to another list but it only picks first record and inserts it 10 times to new list.

When I debug, unique values are shown in the loop but they are not being assigned to left variable.

```
List<Job> jobList=new List<Job>();
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    Job job = new Job();
    job.Title = row.SelectSingleNode("//h2[@class='jobtitle']").ChildNodes[1].Attributes["title"].Value;
    job.summary = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='summary']").InnerText
    jobList.add(job);
}
```

Any idea, what is happening?

I also used garbage collector but still no improvement:

```
job = null;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Here is updated code after @Andrew suggestion but it didn't work. Right side holds updated values but they are not being assigned to left side variables.

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
   try
   {
       var job = new Job();
       var title = row.SelectSingleNode("//h2[@class='jobtitle']").ChildNodes[1].Attributes["title"].Value;
       var company = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='company']").InnerText.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
       var location = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='location']").InnerText.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
       var summary = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='summary']").InnerText.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");

       job.Title = title;
       job.Company = company;
       job.Location = location;
       job.Summary = summary;
       jobList.Add(job);

       job = null;
       GC.Collect();
       GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
       counter++;
       Status("Page# " + pageNumber.ToString() + " : Record# " + counter + " extracted");
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      AppendRecords(jobList);
      jobList.Clear();
   }
   //save file
}
```

Comment: The problem in the way how you retrieve values from xml - you always retrieve same values

Comment: @Fabio - the OP wants to retrieve the same values from each row and the code (at first glance) looks like it should be doing that.

Comment: @Fabio I am using HtmlAgilityPack to to retrieve values & that part is  working fine because I have make sure during debug. The problem is value not being assigned to right side.   
here are screenshots, you can see by yourself

[demo screenshot ](http://screencast.com/t/ZZliIrkXktqq)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I try var but it didn't work

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have update question with the modified code. plz have a look

Comment: Setting `job` equal to null is unnecessary and is probably only complicating things for you.

Comment: Remove `try .. catch` - it will help to find problems.

Comment: Also, remove the GC parts - it will not help.

Comment: @Fabio its not throwing any error

Comment: Can you post your html and the code for rows?

Comment: Hi Experts, I try the proposed solutions but could not find them helpful.
Here is my code
https://github.com/hamad1472/helpme/blob/master/Scraper/Program.cs
you can run it by simply adding HtmlAgilityPack.dll or download complete "scraper" folder, it contain working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You don't tell us what the `rows` variable relates to, but I assume these are nodes in a single XmlDocument.  The XPath expressions you are using to extract values from these nodes is incorrect, because they will always navigate to the same node in the document irrespective of the current `row` node.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates the problem:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
    x.LoadXml(@"<rows> <row><bla><h2>bob1</h2></bla></row> <row><bla><h2>bob2</h2></bla></row> </rows>");
    var rows = x.GetElementsByTagName("row");
    foreach (XmlNode row in rows)
    {
        var h2 = row.SelectSingleNode("//h2").ChildNodes[0].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(h2);
    }
}
```

The output from this will be

```
 bob1
 bob1
```

Not what you were expecting? Have a play with the example in [Dot Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsiFlT).  Take another look at your XPath expression.  Your current expression `//h2` is saying "give me all `h2` elements in the document irrespective of the current node".  Whereas `.//h2` would give you the `h2` elements that are descendants of the current `row` node, which is probably what you need.

Comment: you are right but I have already collected multiple records in rows using this LOC
    HtmlDocument document = web.Load(URL);
                    var rows =   document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@id='resultsCol']//div[@class='  row  result']").ToList();
so in loop rows contain unique 10 records(jobs)

Comment: OK, but each `row` still belongs to the same parent document, so the `SelectSingleNode(//h2)` method is navigating back up to the root of that document and then selecting all `h2` elements.  Try adding "." to the start of your XPath and tell us if that fixes the issue.

Comment: here is working code (with the mentioned problem). 

https://github.com/hamad1472/helpme/blob/master/Scraper/Program.cs

Comment: @Hamad I had a look at the code in your link above.  It is as I thought -  your `row` nodes are references to elements in the original document, so the `//h2` XPath prefix will navigate back up to the root and find all the `h2` elements within the document.  Change the prefix to `.//h2` and I think your program should work.

Comment: it worked... Thanks...
Thanks a lot.. 
:*  :* 
Buddy a lot of love & respect from me..